# Inserting a post in Wordpress using MySql

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Does anyone know how to insert a new post into Wordpress using sql?

Comment: I edited your question. If it's not what you are asking please revert it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the Post object:

```
// Create post object
  $my_post = array();
  $my_post['post_title'] = 'My post';
  $my_post['post_content'] = 'This is my post.';
  $my_post['post_status'] = 'publish';
  $my_post['post_author'] = 1;
  $my_post['post_category'] = array(8,39);

// Insert the post into the database
  wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

More info found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post).

Comment: And which files I have to include? Because I want to do a separate admin panel for wordpress

Comment: BTW, if you want to test this, create a "test.php" file in the root of your blog and use this line before this code: require('./wp-blog-header.php');

Comment: The category needs to be an array of category IDs. That's not easy to get, especially if you don't have posts associated yet with categories. The fix on the category assignment was this: $sCategory='Test';$asPost['post_category']=array($wpdb->get_var("SELECT term_id FROM $wpdb->terms WHERE name='$sCategory'",0,0));

Comment: This is great! You saved the day :)

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to get this to work inside a plugin but it looks like the plugin code isn't able to use WordPress function. Does anybody have an idea on this? Including wp-load isn't really recommended if i'm right.

Answer (score 14):

Your question asks how to insert a new post into WordPress using SQL. If you really wanted to do that, taking a look at the "wp" database tables and do a standard INSERT - this wouldn't be hard.

But I'd **strongly** recommend against doing this - even if you want to create a separate admin dashboard outside of the normal WP-provided one, you should use the [core functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference)/API that they provide.  For example, the [wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) function is what you want to use.

I believe you can use/load these functions by including /wp-load.php.

Comment: I am somewhat new to Wordpress and I am wondering why you recommend against using a basic SQL insert?

Comment: +1 for link to the wp_insert_post function and the details of the file to include for standalone scripts

Comment: @ssergei because Wordpress provides you with an API.

Comment: +1 to that advice. Simply inserting a new row in wp_posts, and adding to a category in wp_term_relationships, doesn't work: the post count updates, but those posts don't show. I'm not sure what else you need to do nowadays.

Answer (score 10):

I started by exporting the "wp_post" table just to see the structure - then copied the first section and wrote the seccond;

1: Start with a variable you can use for your insert statement ($sql)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_parent`, `guid`, `menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`, `comment_count`) VALUES ";
```

2: I took the content that i wanted to insert, from another table - but you can just set the variables either inside or outside of your statement just set the variable to what you desire -

```
$sql .= "(' ','".$post_author."',"."'".$post_date."',"."'".$post_date_gmt."',"."'".$post_content."',"."'".$post_title."',"."'".$post_excerpt."',"."'".$post_status."',"."'".$comment_status."',"."'".$ping_status."',"."'".$posd_password."',"."'".$post_name."',"."'".$to_ping."',"."'".$pinged."',"."'".$post_modified."',"."'".$post_modified_gmt."',"."'".$post_content_filtered."',"."'".$post_parent."',"."'".$guid."',"."'".$menu_order."',"."'".$post_type."',"."'".$post_mime_type."',"."'".$comment_count."'),";
```

After that, use your standard query:

```
$res = mysql_query($sql); if($res): print 'Successful Insert'; else: print 'Unable to update table'; endif;
```

Comment: It won't work, because no category has been assigned to the post, and thus it won't be shown correctly...

Comment: What if it's a CPT and doesn't support wp core categories?

Comment: Some good help in this article as well: https://linkstraffic.net/transfer-wordpress-posts-one-database/