# wp_insert_post() function inside basic plugin

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to achieve the following:

1. Import a XML file
2. Bases on a given field, ['actie'], do a particular action.
3. Insert/Update/Delete posts from the WordPress database.

Step 1 and 2 are working fine but when i'm trying to use the **wp_insert_post()** function inside my code it all stops working and the sending server receives a http 500 response.

I have a file called import.php which receives a call from the sending server. That fill only calls the getCars function.

I've tested the XML with a simpler SQL statement, deleted the $conn for posting purposes, but it works.

Why doesn't my wp_insert_post() work? I've read about including wp-load and stuff but that didn't work either. Note that this code is all inside a WordPress plugin.

```
<?php

function getCars(){

  /*if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '90.145.213.154') {
    // Some security
    exit;
  }*/


  $xmldoc = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $xml = parseXml($xmldoc);

  // Create connection
  switch((string)$xml['actie']) {
    case 'add':
        // Controles uitvoeren
        controleer_voertuig($xml);

        // Add vehicle to DB
        /*$sql = 'INSERT INTO voertuigen (voertuignr_hexon, kenteken, merk) VALUES ('. (string) $xml->voertuignr_hexon .', "'. addslashes((string) $xml->kenteken) .'", "'. addslashes((string) $xml->merk) .'")';*/

      // Create post object
      $args = array(
        'post_title'    => (string) $xml->voertuignr_hexon,
        'post_content'  => 'content',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1,
        'post_category' => array( 8,39 )
      );

      // Insert the post into the database
  wp_insert_post($args,  $wp_error=true);
  print_r($wp_error);




        // ...

        // Foto's opslaan
        //verwerk_fotos($xml->afbeeldingen);
        break;

    case 'change':
        // Controles uitvoeren
        controleer_voertuig($xml);

        // Voertuig wijzigen in database
        /*$sql = 'UPDATE voertuigen SET kenteken = "'. addslashes((string) $xml->kenteken) .'", merk = "'. addslashes((string) $xml->merk) .'" WHERE voertuignr_hexon = '. $xml->voertuignr_hexon .' LIMIT 1';*/
        // ...

        // Foto's opnieuw ophalen
        //verwerk_fotos($xml->afbeeldingen);
        break;

    case 'delete':
        // Voertuig verwijderen uit database
        /*$sql = 'DELETE FROM voertuigen WHERE voertuignr_hexon = '. (string) $xml->voertuignr_hexon .' LIMIT 1'; */
        // ...
        break;
  }

  print("1");
}

function parseXml($xmldoc) {
  // XML inlezen met je favoriete XML-parser. Het voorbeeld gebruikt simpleXML.
  $xml = @simplexml_load_string($xmldoc);

  if(!$xml) {
    // Foutmelding teruggeven aan server van Hexon
    print("Geen geldige XML ontvangen");
    //exit;
}

return $xml;
}

function controleer_voertuig($xml) {
    /*if(empty($xml->fotos)) {
        // Foutmelding teruggeven aan server van Hexon
        print("Op de eigen website zijn alleen voertuigen met foto toegestaan");
        exit;
    }*/
}

function verwerk_fotos($fotos) {
    foreach($fotos as $foto_nr => $foto_url) {
        $bestandsnaam = 'fotos/'. $_GET['hexon_nr'] .'-'. $foto_nr .'.jpg';

        $imgdata = file_get_contents($foto_url);
        file_put_contents($bestandsnaam, $imgdata);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I've used DEBUG_LOG but it only shows some old errors and nothing about not knowing the particular function. Also when I remove the WordPress function wp_insert_post() the function runs fine. Outputting the "1" at the end.

wp-config.php

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
```

LOG (after adding $wp-error to wp_insert_post)

```
[20-Sep-2018 08:42:59 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/vehikel/domains/vehikel.com/public_html/dev//includes/post.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php71/lib/php') in /home/vehikel/domains/vehikel.com/public_html/dev/wp-content/plugins/import-wheeler-delta/index.php on line 18
[20-Sep-2018 09:53:34 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /home/vehikel/domains/vehikel.com/public_html/dev/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 3071
```

Comment: Use [DEBUG_LOG](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) and post the error message.

Comment: it seems you are passing $args array to database without any proper sql structure

Comment: `parseXml` is php function?

Comment: @Michael I've edited my question.

Comment: @charankumar The visible SQL statements are for testing purposes. I'm trying to use the wp_insert_post() function. Stated in this answer why I shouldn't use SQL statements. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670838/inserting-a-post-in-wordpress-using-mysql

Comment: @Vel parseXml is defined at the bottom, It is working. Purely the wp_insert_post() isn't working.

Comment: Please 
- Paste your debug enabled errors/warnings here even if they seem irrelevant to you.
- Set $wp_error as true so that wp_insert_posts() returns the error and print it.

Comment: you didnt add `post_type` in $args?

Comment: @UmairKhanJadoon I've edited my question.

Comment: It seems like you are passing an empty var to your include/require statements: `/dev//includes`. Make sure the path is valid to solve the fatal error. What does this line look like: `"plugins/import-wheeler-delta/index.php on line 18"`?

Comment: @Michael That's an old error. I've removed the requires. Tried to load the wp-load.php and the post.php.

Comment: If you can post your XML file here or it's link, I will to run your code at my end and help you further diagnose the problem.